# InvalidOperationException in editing user role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I get this problem whenever I save the changes I made when changing the roles of a user:

> *An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional
>   information: The ViewData item that has the key 'URole' is of type
>   'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable*

These are the codes of my GET and POST Edit

```
// GET: /AccountAdmin/Edit/5

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

    Account account = db.Accounts.Find(id);
    if (account == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    RoleDropDownList(account.URole);
    return View(account);
}

//
// POST: /AccountAdmin/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Account account)
{
    try
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        RoleDropDownList(account.URole);
        return View(account);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return View(account);
    }
}
 private void RoleDropDownList(object selectedRole = null)
    {
        var q = from a in db.Roles
                orderby a.RoleID
                select a;
        ViewBag.URole = new SelectList(q, "RoleID", "UserRole", selectedRole);
    }
```

And this is the Edit View

```
 @model MvcApplication3.Models.Account

    @ViewBag.Title = "Edit";

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AccID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.URole, "Role")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("URole", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.URole)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

        @section Scripts{
            <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/jqueryval")"></script>
        }
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the error occur? At `RoleDropDownList(account.URole);`?

Comment: @Serv At the view `<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("URole", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.URole)
        </div>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("URole", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.URole)
</div>
```

This snippet getting URole from model property. Which may be an integer. So giving expection while enumerating through `int`. Here is an alternate approach to handle this.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

   Account account = db.Accounts.Find(id);
   if (account == null)
   {
      return HttpNotFound();
   }
   RoleDropDownList(account.URole); // Assuming RoleDropDownList returns a SelectList
   return View(account);
}
```

And then in view.

```
@Html.DropDownList("URole",ViewBag.Roles as SelectList,string.Empty,  
 new { @name= "URole" });
```

Comment: This is my RoleDropDownList  `private void RoleDropDownList(object selectedRole = null)
        {
            var q = from a in db.Roles
                    orderby a.RoleID
                    select a;
            ViewBag.URole = new SelectList(q, "RoleID", "UserRole", selectedRole);
        }`

Comment: Change the ViewBag.URole to ViewBag.Roles to avoid conflict/confusion between model's property and ViewBag's property.

Comment: If I use this code `ViewBag.Roles = RoleDropDownList(account.URole);` I am getting an error that says : "Cannot implicitly convert 'void' to 'dynamic'"

Comment: This is because i assumed your 'RoleDropDownList' function returning a DropDownList.  Now I have updated the answer. check it.

Comment: Thank you for this sir. But now it is throwing me some kind of new exception with regards to the DB. I think it is already working but just having some conflicts with saving the changes to the DB. Thank you so much!